# Can a length n distributive lattice be embedded into Bn?

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, lattice-theory

Let  $\mathcal{L}$ be a  finite distributive lattice, then it is known that it can be embedded into a finite boolean lattice (see  theorem 8.5. p91 in [this note](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os8uh.pdf)).

Let $n$ be the length of $\mathcal{L}$  and let $\mathcal{B}_n$ be the boolean lattice of rank $n$.

*Question*:  Can $\mathcal{L}$ be embedded into $\mathcal{B}_n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A distributive lattice $L$ of length $n$ is isomorphic to the set of order ideals of an $n$-element poset $P$, ordered by inclusion. This is the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Distributive Lattices, first proved by Garrett Birkhoff. Thus $L$ imbeds into the boolean algebra of all subsets of $P$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_representation_theorem

Comment: @DavidEppstein: if I'm not mistaken, this page does not precise that a length $n$ distributive lattice admits exactly $n$ join-irreducible elements.  Anyway, I've found the more complete statement in the book [Lattice theory](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lattice_Theory.html?id=0Y8d-MdtVwkC) of Garett Birkhoff, corollary 2 p59.

Comment: Another reference is Section 3.4 of my book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second edition.